Shimano 105 FC-R7100 crankset on a 10 speed cassette
I have a Shimano Ultegra 6750 crankset with worn out chainrings that need to be replaced. A Shimano 105 12 speed crankset is cheaper and more readily available in my market than replacement rings. From other posts my understanding is that it most likely will work well as the inner links on the chain are the same on 10, 11 and 12 speed chains.
Will a Shimano 105 12 speed crankset work fine with the 10 speed cassette? If it does, what chain would work best with this setup (10, 11 or 12 speed)?

Why not other 10-speed chainrings? Older 105 or Tiagra? Surely must be cheaper than a new crankset.

Even if not chainrings, then just a new Tiagra crankset is somewhat heavier, but you avoid any incompatibilities. The shifting should be more certain. BTW I do see the Ultegra 6750 chainrings in eshops.

I think it would be OK. It is when you cross-chain the 34 to the 11 that problems occur, but this is an "illegal" gear combination anyway.

@VladimirFГероямслава Yes, there might be some older 105 chainrings that fit the Ultegra 6750, but from my research its difficult to find a 110cbd 5 arm chainring (at least with similar Hollowtech design).
There are a few Ultegra 6750 chainrings to buy here in Norway, however they are priced almost the same as a new 105 crankset. A Tiagra crankset is also similarly priced, so my thought was that a new 105 crankset would be the better solution (if it fits).

@Nicolai I doubt introducing unnecessary speed difference would be the better solution. I certainly see no reason for that.

Also, from what I see here, the 105 R7100 crankset costs about 50% more of what Tiagra  R4700 crankset costs.
